# List of examples of commutative rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

For curiosity:

Can anyone present the currently known list of examples of commutative rings? As Wikipedia says, one may include polynomial rings, rings of algebraic integers and p-adic integers. What more can be added to the list?

Comment: i guess all examples can't be put by someone !

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Asking for "the currently known list of examples" sounds like asking at least for all known examples (if not literally a classification) to me. But I guess that might not be the intent of the question.

Comment: Every commutative ring is the image of $\mathbb Z[\{x_i\}_{i\in I}]$ for some set $I$.

Comment: @MattPressland Whoops, skipped past that sentence.

Comment: @MattPressland That is my intent.

Comment: @DOWN Then almost certainly nothing useful can be said; as far as I'm aware, there are far too many examples even to give a list of families. Probably the best that can be said is that all commutative rings are quotients of a free commutative ring (which probably amounts to the same thing Thomas has already said).

Answer (score 2):

As I said above, if $S$ is any set, then there is a polynomial ring $$\mathbb Z[S]$$ which has one indeterminate $x_s$ for each $s\in S$.

Any commutative ring (with identity) can be written as $\mathbb Z[S]/I$ for some set $S$ and some ideal $I$ of $\mathbb Z[S]$. But that is sort of trivially true. This representation isn't much use, because different $S,J$ can give us isomorphic rings.

I don't think you are going to get a nice characterization of commutative rings, unfortunately.

Given an abelian group, $A$, the set of homomorphisms $\phi: A\to A$ (or "endomorphisms of $A$) form a ring, and it is an interesting representation of rings that every ring, commutative or not, is a sub-ring of such an endomorphism ring. This does not help us much to understand commutativity, however, because the multiplication of $\phi,\rho:A\to A$, is function composition, so what does it mean that all of our homomorphisms commute?

Comment: In the field of algebraic geometry, commutative rings are treated as geometric in nature. I've always wondered of there is a deep relationship there that I'm missing, because when we "show" that $3\times 4$ is the same as $4\times 3$ to  small child, we essentially make a geometric argument by rotating a rectangle. But the "geometry" of a field is trivial in algebraic geometry, and we consider the goemetry of fields $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$ as our intuitive basis for geometry.